# Return 2 row above and 2 row ahead in SELECT

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

friends,

I would like to create a query to return me 2 lines above and 2 lines below the selected ID, but the comparison must be made by the ranking.

Query that creates a league table.

```
SET @rowId :=0;
SELECT 
    @rowid:= @rowid + 1 AS ranking, 
    tabelaCompleta.*
FROM
(SELECT 
    tbl_timeCartola.nomeTime AS nomeTime, 
    SUM( tbl_ponto.ponto ) AS totalPontos, 
    tbl_timeCartola.FK_loginID
FROM tbl_ponto
INNER JOIN tbl_timeCartola ON tbl_timeCartola.FK_loginID = tbl_ponto.FK_loginID
WHERE tbl_timeCartola.FK_loginID IN ( SELECT FK_loginID FROM tbl_campeonatoUsuario WHERE FK_campeonatoID = '1' )
GROUP BY tbl_timeCartola.nomeTime
ORDER BY totalPontos DESC ) tabelaCompleta;
```

This query return this:

```
+---------+-------------------+-------------+------------+
| ranking | nomeTime          | totalPontos | FK_loginID |
+---------+-------------------+-------------+------------+
|       1 | Mathemio Greus-SB |      612.90 |          7 |
|       2 | CR Hipotenusa VG  |      572.67 |          4 |
|       3 | Zica Danada       |      549.20 |          6 |
|       4 | FC LEEDS UNITED   |      516.12 |          8 |
|       5 | Bradock  F.C      |      503.51 |          5 |
+---------+-------------------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Question is a little unclear (to me): from the table the query returned, what are you looking to get?

Comment: From the userid I need to get the rank and return 1 line above and 1 abaxio line. Apologize for my English.

Comment: where is `userid`? `FK_loginID` in the result set?

Comment: Skram, thanks for ajduar me, but honestly I've tried everything: (
I'm not expert query, I need the code yourself, do not be lazy but realemten think I've tried everything: (

Comment: Skram, in tbltimeCartola table

Comment: @GustavoFilgueiras So, if you select FK_loginID=8, then ranking=3,4,5 must be listed. If you select FK_loginID=5, then ranking=4,5 must be listed. Is that correct?

Comment: @JosephB Perfect, this is exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. The rankings are derived in two different inline views. Then, they are joined using the ranking (if the second inline view's ranking is -1,=, or +1 than the first inline view's ranking). The data is filtered for the `selectedId`.

```
SET @rowId1 :=0;
SET @rowId2 :=0;
SET @selectedId := 8;

SELECT
    tabela_ordenada2.*
FROM
(
SELECT 
    @rowId1 := @rowId1 + 1 AS ranking, 
    tabelaCompleta.*
FROM
(SELECT 
    tbl_timeCartola.nomeTime AS nomeTime, 
    SUM( tbl_ponto.ponto ) AS totalPontos, 
    tbl_timeCartola.FK_loginID AS FK_loginID
FROM tbl_ponto
INNER JOIN tbl_timeCartola ON tbl_timeCartola.FK_loginID = tbl_ponto.FK_loginID
WHERE tbl_timeCartola.FK_loginID IN ( SELECT FK_loginID FROM tbl_campeonatoUsuario WHERE FK_campeonatoID = '1' )
GROUP BY tbl_timeCartola.nomeTime
ORDER BY totalPontos DESC ) tabelaCompleta
) tabela_ordenada1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT 
    @rowId2 := @rowId2 + 1 AS ranking, 
    tabelaCompleta.*
FROM
(SELECT 
    tbl_timeCartola.nomeTime AS nomeTime, 
    SUM( tbl_ponto.ponto ) AS totalPontos, 
    tbl_timeCartola.FK_loginID AS FK_loginID
FROM tbl_ponto
INNER JOIN tbl_timeCartola ON tbl_timeCartola.FK_loginID = tbl_ponto.FK_loginID
WHERE tbl_timeCartola.FK_loginID IN ( SELECT FK_loginID FROM tbl_campeonatoUsuario WHERE FK_campeonatoID = '1' )
GROUP BY tbl_timeCartola.nomeTime
ORDER BY totalPontos DESC ) tabelaCompleta
) tabela_ordenada2
ON (tabela_ordenada2.ranking = tabela_ordenada1.ranking - 1 OR tabela_ordenada2.ranking = tabela_ordenada1.ranking OR tabela_ordenada2.ranking = tabela_ordenada1.ranking + 1)
WHERE tabela_ordenada1.FK_loginID = @selectedId;
```

Comment: Unbelievable, you were perfect, thank you very much for your help
if you have gtalk, add me, gfilgueirasrj@gmail.com

Comment: If I wanted to bring 2 results for each side, as I do?

Comment: Change the second to last line as `ON (tabela_ordenada2.ranking >= tabela_ordenada1.ranking - 2 AND tabela_ordenada2.ranking <= tabela_ordenada1.ranking + 2)`. You can use this expression for 1 row on either side, too - replace 2 with 1.

Comment: Thank you, you have no idea how to help me

Comment: Yeah, I do have a gmail id, but do not use gtalk.